# Net Core 3.1 no session in iframe

Tags: iframe, .net-core, samesite

When we embed our app (net core 3.1, single page application with vuejs) in an iframe on a page on a another domain, requests for session variables are always null

Good to know:
When entering the page the user is first asked to fill out a name which is then stored in a session.

This mechanism works fine if the page is embedded on a page on the same domain (our website) but when the app is called from an iframe on another domain, sessions are always null.

I read a few posts about the 'samesite cookie' which is I guess the way to configure and solve this?
I have tried some solutions and examples but I do not experience any difference.

This is the code from the startup.cs.
Quit long..sorry for that..!

I have disabled all samesite settings
Which settings are required to make this work?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            //options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false; // consent required
            //options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });



        services.AddSession(opts =>
        {
            opts.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            //opts.Cookie.Name = "livestreamsupport.session";
            opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

            opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            //opts.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; 
            //opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;

        });


        //Add service for accessing current HttpContext
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        //services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

        //add custom services
        services.AddTransient<ISurvey, Survey>();
        services.AddTransient<IQuestion, Question>();

        //services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

        services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationContext>(
              options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
              mySqlOptions =>
              {
                  mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 17), ServerType.MySql)
                  .EnableRetryOnFailure(
                  maxRetryCount: 10,
                  maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                  errorNumbersToAdd: null);
              })
        );

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();


        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        });

        //services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        //{
        //    //options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
        //    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        //    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        //});

        services.AddAuthorization();

        //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        //    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        //    //options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        //    //options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
        //    //options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
        //});

        //services.AddAntiforgery(opts => {
        //    opts.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        //});

        services.AddSignalR();
    }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();

        var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "en" };
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
            .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
            .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        //{
        //    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
        //});

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        //app.UseCors();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            //zorg ervoor dat geen gebruik kan worden gemaakt van de default identity routes
            endpoints.MapGet("/Identity/Account/Login",context => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login", true, true)));

            //endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "api",
                    pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "survey", action = "getpollresults" });


        });

        //maak de httpcontext beschikbaar in de applicatie
        AppHttpContext.Services = app.ApplicationServices;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following tags to the web.config <system.webServer> tag make sessions in iframe work. The SameSite=None does the trick.

```
<rewrite>
<outboundRules>
  <clear />
  <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None;Secure=true" />
  </rule>
  <preConditions>
    <preCondition name="No SameSite">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None;Secure=true" negate="true" />
    </preCondition>
  </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

I hoped I could find the right setting in the net core 3.1. application instead of configuring IIS on the webserver but most important is that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sites embedded within another site via an iframe are in a cross-site context, meaning all their cookies are considered as third-party by the browser and as a result must specify `SameSite=None` and `Secure` in their attributes.

This is supported as of .net 4.72: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

If you cannot update the .net implementation you *might* be able to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/aspnet.md to patch.

Alternatively, you may be able to use a proxy, e.g. your webserver, to alter the `set-cookie` header in the outbound responses in order to add the necessary `SameSite=None; Secure` to each one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The information is much and detailed and hard for me understand , sorry.  
I have tried the outbound rule method in IIS, we have access to the (virtual) server. 
That does not make a difference unfortunately. Sessions still get lost. (expire on page refresh). All we want is showing a already good working webpage (when not in an iframe) in an iframe. It must probably be a (simple) setting but I can not figure out which one!

Comment: Now it works. Adding the following tags to the web.config make sessions in iframe work.